# JQM Caching of page- how to specify the duration

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a site with multiple html files. For some of the page, am setting data-dom-cache="true". But, i do not want the page to be cached forever. Is there any way to specify the duration for which the page should be cached. What should be done for this in JQM.

Answer (score 2):

In jQuery Mobile there is not a DOM cache expiration time setting but you can handle manually the removal from DOM.

In order to remove a page from DOM you have to use:

```
$('#page-id').remove();
```

Comment: Am aware of this remove method. But, when should this be done. Is there any better way of doing this say for every five minutes. Can you point me to some resource where this is done.

Comment: You can get an idea from this implementation: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/new-attribute-dom-cache-expires-120

Comment: This solution works. But, there are two issues:1. Reloading of the page, will reload the entire DOM,t  which is not intended. It should re-load only that page 2. This solution is implemented in pageshow method, which causes a delay in getting the data and this affects the UI rendering.

Comment: A possible workaround is to check which pages have expired and remove them from DOM using jQuery `.remove()` method (this should not be done for the page you're navigating to) instead of performing a page reload.